# How to obtain the unitary operator to get specific partial trace?

Tags: quantum-operation, linear-algebra

Is there a unitary $U_{AB}$ such that, for any density operator $\rho$, we have
$${\rm {Tr}}_A \left[U_{AB} \left(\frac{I_A}{2} \otimes \rho_B\right)U_{AB}^{\dagger}\right]= \frac{\rho_B}{2}+\frac{I_B}{4}
\\
{\rm {Tr}}_B \left[U_{AB} \left(\frac{I_A}{2} \otimes \rho_B\right)U_{AB}^{\dagger}\right]= \frac{\rho_A}{2}+\frac{I_A}{4},$$
where $I_A=I_B=I$ is the identity matrix, $\rho_A=\rho_B=\rho$, A and B are both single qubit systems.

I have thought about decomposing $U_{AB}$ to express the partial trace but failed. I also considered about searching for such unitary, but $U_{AB}$ and $\rho$ are both unknown, which holds me back. Any ideas or comments, both in the analytic way or a computation way, would be appreciated.

It seems that symmetry can be used to derive the proof.

---

***Cross-posted on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4531503/173147) and [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/727756/how-to-obtain-the-unitary-operator-to-get-specific-partial-trace)***

Comment: How are you defining $\rho_{AB}$?

Comment: It is not given. I have assumed that $\rho_{AB} = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$. Then we can have $I_A/2=\rho_A=\rho_B=\rho=I/2$ according to the conditions. In this case, we can obtain the results above. But this is not what the original problem's intention. So the assumption $\rho_{AB} = \rho_A \otimes \rho_B$ is not right.

Comment: @Michael.Andy is this a problem from somewhere? If so, can you link to the source?

Comment: @glS: This problem is designed by a quantum computation researcher. So no links.

Comment: @glS: What do you think about the definition of $\rho_{AB}$ in this problem?

Comment: @Michael.Andy what do you mean what do I think of it? You're asking the condition to be verified for all $\rho$ such that $\rho_A=\rho_B$. Or am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: @glS: Your understanding is right.

Comment: @gLS: My question is whether $\rho_{AB} = I_A/2 \otimes 
\rho_B$ in this problem?

Comment: @Michael.Andy I don't understand the question in that comment. You just said that the condition should be verified by any $\rho_{AB}$ with identical marginals. Now you're saying that is not the case?

Comment: @gls: My understanding may be wrong. Just focus on the original problem.

Comment: @Michael.Andy sorry, I'm not following. I am only looking at the problem as you stated it in the question. I have no idea what the "original problem" is

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS$ where $S$ is swap that $S|i\rangle\otimes|j\rangle=|j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the unitary is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS$ where $S$ is swap operator such that $S|i\rangle\otimes|j\rangle=|j\rangle\otimes|i\rangle$, and have matrix form $S=\sum_{ij}{|ij\rangle \langle ji|}$. The original idea is to mix two unitary matrices, while generally not a unitary matrix, hence I add $i$ before $S$.

Mind that $$U_{AB}\frac{I}{2}\otimes {\rho U_{AB}}^{\dagger}
\\
=\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS \right) \left( \frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho \right) \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS \right) ^{\dagger}
\\
=\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS \right) \left( \frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho \right) \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}I-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}iS \right) 
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho -\frac{i}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho S+\frac{i}{2}S\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho +\frac{1}{2}S\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho S
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho +\frac{1}{2}\rho \otimes \frac{I}{2}+\frac{i}{2}S\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho -\frac{i}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho S$$
Then we only need to calculate $Tr_B$ of it, I only show that $Tr_B\left( \frac{i}{2}S\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho -\frac{i}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho S \right) =0$, the residual part is easy to show. This part may be calculated with tensor graph type method while I am not familiar with it, so I directly expand the index as follows:
$$Tr_B\left( \frac{i}{2}S\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho -\frac{i}{2}\frac{I}{2}\otimes \rho S \right) 
\\
=Tr_B\left( \frac{i}{2}\sum_{ij}{|ij\rangle \langle ji|}\frac{\sum_k{|k\rangle \langle k|}}{2}\otimes \sum_{mn}{\rho _{mn}|m\rangle \langle n|}-\frac{i}{2}\frac{\sum_k{|k\rangle \langle k|}}{2}\otimes \sum_{mn}{\rho _{mn}|m\rangle \langle n|}\sum_{ij}{|ij\rangle \langle ji|} \right) 
\\
=Tr_B\left( \frac{i}{4}\sum_{ijn}{\rho _{in}|ij\rangle \langle jn|}-\frac{i}{4}\sum_{ijm}{\rho _{mj}}|im\rangle \langle ji| \right) 
\\
=\frac{i}{4}\sum_{ij}{\rho _{ij}|i\rangle \langle j|}-\frac{i}{4}\sum_{ij}{\rho _{ij}}|i\rangle \langle j|=0.$$

As for $Tr_A$, I think the calculation should be the same.

Comment: Great! How do you come up with the idea of constructing such a unitary matrix?

Comment: @Michael.Andy Mix $I$ and $S$ with probability. While adding them up directly I didn't get a unitary, so I added an $i$ in front of $S$.

Comment: @Michael.Andy By setting $U=I$ and $U=S$, we get partial trace is $\rho$ and $I/2$, hence a mix of them two will get the right answer, while setting $U$ in the answer form, there will be 4 terms so I *hope* the two terms that I don't want can cancel them out. Luckily they did.

Comment: Great! Thank you narip!

Comment: Could you recommend some related books to me?

Comment: @Michael.Andy What kind of book? For quantum computation and quantum information, I think a great book is Nielsen and Chuang's book(I personally read this one), also John Preskill's [lecture notes](http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/). If you tend to like the style contains more math, you can read John Watrous' [The Theory of Quantum Information](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! Does Nielsen and Chuang's book contain all the materials related to the above problems? (I have only read part of Nielsen and Chuang's book now. ) I can figure it out following your answer using what I've learned, but I did not come up with the idea that you provide. So I want to improve myself.

Comment: @Michael.Andy Actually the skill I use only needs an understanding of partial trace and the operator $S$. So in this sense, the book definitely covers all the material. The rest is just how you can grasp the subtle feelings when you see the problem(More practice will help a lot). You also mentioned in your question that symmetry might help. So in this sense, how to solve a question cannot be covered by any book :-). One more thing, guessing is imortant.

Comment: The Swap operator that I hadn't learned before plays an important role  here. This prevents me from solving the problem. Your insights are very helpful!